# Incompatible type with Arrays.asList()

Tags: java, generics

In the following example, if I have multiple types in the list it compiles ok, but if I have one element, it chooses a different type which is no longer assignable.

```
// compiles fine
List<Class<? extends Reference>> list = Arrays.asList(SoftReference.class, WeakReference.class);
// but take an element away and it no longer compiles.
List<Class<? extends Reference>> list2 = Arrays.asList(WeakReference.class);
// without giving the specific type desired.
List<Class<? extends Reference>> list3 = Arrays.<Class<? extends Reference>>asList(WeakReference.class);
```

I am sure there is a logical explaination for this, but it escapes me.

```
    Error:Error:line (30)error: incompatible types
required: List<Class<? extends Reference>>
found:    List<Class<WeakReference>>
```

Why does having two elements compile but one element does not?

BTW: It is hard to find a simple example, if you try

```
List<Class<? extends List>> list = Arrays.asList(ArrayList.class, LinkedList.class);

    Error:Error:line (28)error: incompatible types
required: List<Class<? extends List>>
found:    List<Class<? extends INT#1>>
where INT#1 is an intersection type:
INT#1 extends AbstractList,Cloneable,Serializable
```

This doesn't compile either (it won't even parse)

```
List<Class<? extends AbstractList & Cloneable & Serializable>> list = Arrays.asList(ArrayList.class, LinkedList.class);

Error:Error:line (30)error: > expected
Error:Error:line (30)error: ';' expected
```

but this compiles fine

```
static abstract class MyList<T> implements List<T> { }
List<Class<? extends List>> list = 
        Arrays.asList(ArrayList.class, LinkedList.class, MyList.class);
List<Class<? extends List>> list = 
        Arrays.<Class<? extends List>>asList(ArrayList.class, LinkedList.class);
```

---

EDIT: Based on Marko's example. In these four example, one doesn't compile, the rest produce the same list of the same type.

```
List<Class<? extends Reference>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(SoftReference.class);
list.add(WeakReference.class);
list.add(PhantomReference.class);

List<Class<? extends Reference>> list = new ArrayList<>(
     Arrays.asList(SoftReference.class));
list.add(WeakReference.class);
list.add(PhantomReference.class);

List<Class<? extends Reference>> list = new ArrayList<>(
     Arrays.asList(SoftReference.class, WeakReference.class));
list.add(PhantomReference.class);

List<Class<? extends Reference>> list = new ArrayList<>(
     Arrays.asList(SoftReference.class, WeakReference.class, PhantomReference.class));
```

Comment: I think that the compiler in jdk < 7 asks for the two parts of the statement to have the same declaration. also not 100% sure that this is what causing the problem!!

Comment: I am using Java 7 update 9.

Comment: then as i think you either add the same declaration in both sides of the statement or not to declare it at all in the second part.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan I agree that is a work around as I have found. I am curious to know why the rules for implicit casting appear to be different in differnt situations

Comment: What's the error message with `List<Class<? extends AbstractList & Cloneable & Serializable>> list`? It looks to me like it should parse.

Comment: @TedHopp It doesn't like the `&` syntax.

Comment: @TedHopp: not sure that an upper bounded wildcard can extend several classes, this would allow multiple inheritance otherwise in my understanding...

Comment: generic class declaration is required for the compiler to understand the statements. even when you are using "asList" method.

Comment: @fge - The additional bounds (those following `&`) can only be interface names (see [JLS 4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4), so I don't see how it would allow multiple inheritance to sneak in.

Comment: @fge You can define a generic type with `<T extends AbstractList & Cloneable & Serializable>` provided only the first type can be a class, but it doesn't help here.

Comment: @TedHopp I would call it multiple inhertance of interfaces, just not classes. ;)

Comment: Heh. And we all know the trouble that causes. :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey a type, yes, not a wildcard

Comment: @fge - Perhaps you could explain your point a little more. A wildcard just says "some type consistent with the specified bounds". Whether the bounds are a single class name or a class name with additional bounds in the form of interfaces doesn't seem to me to make any difference.

Comment: All the cases make sense to me, I still don't see the tension you want to create between the working and non-working cases. `Class<WeakReference>` *is-not-a* `Class<? extends WeakReference>` so naturally you can't assign. The example does point out the weakness of the generic type system, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Interesting problem. I think that what's going on is this. When you have two elements like you show, the return type from `asList` is most specific type of all the arguments, which in your first example is `List<Reference>`. This is assignment-compatible with `List<? extends Reference>`. When you have a single argument, the return type is the specific type of the argument, which is not assignment-compatible because generics are not covariant.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Oops--wrong word. I meant "covariant". Updated the answer.

Comment: It appears to me that the rules for implicit casting are different in different situations. There must be some logic which says it's ok to cast one way with asList which it cannot do with an assignment.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Computing the intersection (all that the compiler has to do with calls to `asList`) is never a problem--at worst you end up with `Object`. It's no surprise, though, that the rules for resolving generics in an assignment statement are different from rules for method calls. Or did I misunderstand your point?

Comment: It is a surprise to me as I have always thought of arguments being assigned to method parameters.  Even accepting that they might have different rules, is a good reason to do this?  Perhaps a completely different example...

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I phrased that wrong. The rules are the same, but the cases are different, so different aspects of the rules apply. Each actual argument is being assigned to a parameter that is the intersection type of all the actual parameters. Pretty much by definition of the intersection type, this cannot cause a problem. The assignment statement, on the other hand, assigns the intersection type to a generic type specified by your code. That's when there can be a problem (in this case because generic types are not covariant).

Comment: This explanation is wrong on several counts: first of all, `List<WeakReference>` is assignment-compatible with `List<? extends Reference>`. Second, the question is not about these types, but about `List<Class<? extends Reference>>` -- and only there the trouble begins, because now there's no wildcard capture happening. Also take note that generic types would be broken if they were covariant, so it's not much of an explanation.

Answer (score 10):

Consider

```
    // ok
    List<Object> list3 = Arrays.asList(new Object(), new String());
    // fail
    List<Object> list4 = Arrays.asList(new String());
```

The 2nd example tries to assigne a `List<String>` to a `List<Object>`, which fails.

The 2nd example could work, if javac looks at the surrounding context, takes into account the target type, and deduce that `T=Object` would work here. Java 8 will probably do that (I'm not sure)

Only in one situation, javac (of java 5) will use contextual info for type inference, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.8

We can take advantage of that to make a workaround

```
public static <R, T extends R> List<R> toList(T... elements)
{
    return Arrays.asList((R[])elements);
}
```

Now they can be compiled:

```
    List<Object> list4 = toList(new String());

    List<Class<? extends Reference>> list = toList(SoftReference.class, WeakReference.class);

    List<Class<? extends Reference>> list2 = toList(WeakReference.class);
```

This is because `R` cannot be inferred from argument types, and the method result is in an assignment context, so javac tries to infer `R` by the target type.

This works in assignment, or in a return statement

```
List<Class<? extends Reference>> foo()
{
    return toList(WeakReference.class);  // "subject to assignment conversion"
}
```

It won't work otherwise

```
void bar(List<Class<? extends Reference>> list){...}

bar( toList(WeakReference.class) ); // fail; R not inferred
```

Comment: +1, this is the correct answer. The key is in the first line of JLS §15.12.2.8: "**If any of the method's type arguments were not inferred from the types of the actual arguments,** they are now inferred as follows...." Since the type of the returned list *is* inferred from the actual arguments in the case of `Arrays.asList()`, the rules for contextual inference do not apply.

Comment: You'll still need to add `@SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")` to the `toList` method. Without it I get an `Unchecked generics array creation for varargs parameter` warning.

Comment: `List <Object> list4 = toList(new String());` doesn't compile (incompatible types). Please fix your answer.

Comment: Your `toList` method is problematic. The `List` returned from `Arrays.asList` is backed by the array passed in. You have a `List<Object>` which throws `ArrayStoreException` if you put `Object` in it. See http://ideone.com/vcuGfS.

Answer (score 4):

There are two parts to the explanation of this behavior:

1. How does the type of the right-hand side change with changing arguments?
2. Why are some of the RHS types incompatible with the LHS type?

#### 1. The Right-Hand Side

The signature of `asList` is

```
<T> List<T> asList(T... a)
```

This means that all the arguments must be conflated into a single type `T`, which is the *most specific type common to the types of all arguments*. In this particular case, we have

```
asList(WeakReference.class) -> List<Class<WeakReference>>
```

and

```
asList(WeakReference.class, SoftReference.class) 
   -> List<Class<? extends Reference>>
```

Both of these are obvious enough.

#### 2. The Left-Hand Side

Now, why can't we assign the first expression, of type `List<Class<WeakReference>>`, to a variable of type `List<Class<? extends Reference>>`? The best way to understand why the rules must be so is proof by contradiction. Consider the following:

- `List<Class<? extends Reference>>` has `add(Class<? extends Reference>)`
- `List<Class<WeakReference>>` has `add(Class<WeakReference>)`.

Now, if Java allowed you to assign one to the other:

```
List<Class<WeakReference>> lw = new ArrayList<>();
List<Class<? extends Reference>> lq = lw;
lq.add(PhantomReference.class);
```

it would result in a clear violation of type safety.

Answer (score 2):

This is interesting:

```
where INT#1 is an intersection type:
INT#1 extends AbstractList,Cloneable,Serializable
```

Maybe that is the cause for (some of the) issues?

The *intersection* type of the elements may not be uniquely determined. When you declare your own list `MyList<T> implements List<T>`, the intersection type of the array is determined as `List<T>`.

When using `Arrays.<Class<? extends List>>asList(ArrayList.class, LinkedList.class);` the 'intersection' type is explicitly stated (as `List`) and does not need to be inferred by the compiler.

Besides that, I believe what Ted Hopp said is correct for the other case.

EDIT:

The difference between

```
List<Class<? extends Reference>> list2 = Arrays.asList(WeakReference.class);
```

and

```
List<Class<? extends Reference>> list3 = Arrays.<Class<? extends Reference>>asList(WeakReference.class);
```

may be the point in time when the compiler determines the new list's type: I figure it needs to determine the generic type of the list *before* considering the assignment. For this it takes the information it has to infer the type of the new list *without* regard to the assignment. This may cause two different types of list to be created by the two statements above, resulting in the observed behavior.

Comment: +1 I agree which is why I created the dummy MyList the way I did to restrict the intersection of types.